# Haskell: How to delete the same function and concatenate two lists

Tags: haskell

I am the beginner of haskell. I want to delete some same functions in the same list and concatenate the two list get together.
For example:

```
db1 = ["David","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ] 
db2 = ["David","isa'.worksfor'", "IBM"] 
db3 = ["Tom","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ]
```

the program can be known that "isa'.worksfor' and "worksfor.isa" is the same String. And then use "Concat" to get the new `db`: `db1 =["David","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ]` and the others: `db3 = ["Tom","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ]`

```
(map (\(a,b,c) -> concat (map(\(a',b',c') -> if ( a b == b' a')  then [] else [(a,b ++ "." ++ b',c')]))))  ??????
```

I want to "split the string, if there are ' characters, reverse it, then remove ' characters and check for equivalence"

Comment: When you say "delete", do you mean `filter`?

Comment: It means that if db1 = ["David","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ] db2 =["David","isa'.worksfor'", "IBM"] ,we only use "worksfor.isa" and concatenate db1 and db2 get together as db =["David","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ]

Comment: I am sorry, it's difficult for me to understand your question. Can you add more examples? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you so much. I there are two db. ,db1 = ["David","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ]   db2 =["David","isa'.worksfor'", "IBM"]. the program can be known that  "isa'.worksfor' and "worksfor.isa" is the same function. And then use "Concat" to get the new db  :db =["David","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ]

Comment: Can you please give a different example?

Comment: When you say "function" what exactly do you mean? Not a Haskell function, right? Because it looks like a String.

Comment: I there are two db. ,db1 = ["David","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ] db2 =["David","isa'.worksfor'", "IBM"]. db3 = ["Tom","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ]the program can be known that "isa'.worksfor' and "worksfor.isa" is the same String. And then use "Concat" to get the new db :db1 =["David","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ] and the others : db3 = ["Tom","worksfor.isa", "IBM" ].

Comment: It is difficult to read code in comments; please edit the question instead.

Comment: With Haskell it always helps to give us the *type* of the function you're trying to write.

Comment: I you can give me a example? TKS

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) then use the [edit] button to fix your formatting.

Answer (score 6):

This should be a comment, but it is far too long:

I assume you find it hard to express yourself in English. I can relate to that; I find it hard myself. However, beyond English there are two other ways to communicate here:

1. Using precise technical terms.
2. Using several, diverse examples. A single example will not suffice, and several examples which are too similar give little information.

As for option 1, you are using the wrong terminology. It is not easy for me to see how can a list with 3 items can be considered a database (as hinted by the names `db1`, `db2`). Perhaps you wanted to use a list of triples?

```
[ ("David","isa'.worksfor'", "IBM") ]
```

You are not specific about what exactly do you want to concatenate, but the term `concatenation` *always* refers to an operation that must be "additive", i.e. `length(x ++ y) == length(x) ++ length(y)`. This does not seem to be the case in your question.

Do you want a *union* of two databases (lists of triples) up to equivalence?

You want the program to understand that

> "isa'.worksfor'" and "worksfor.isa" are the same string

But they are not. They might be *equivalent* strings. You can generally do that using a map operation, like you tried, but you should note that the character `'` is not an operation over strings. So `a b == b' a'` does nothing close to what you want - it calls the function `a` on the variable `b`, and compares this with calling the *function* `b'` over the variable `a'`. I can only assume you want something like "split the string, if there are `'` characters, reverse it, then remove `'` characters and check for equivalence" but this is completely a guesswork.

To conclude:

1. Please explain in detail what is the general problem you are trying to solve. Try to find the precise terms; it is difficult, but this way you can learn.
2. Please add different examples of input and output
3. Please try to explain what have you tried and where are you stuck

As a last tip, maybe you want to solve this problem in a more forgiving language than Haskell (such as JavaScript, Python, Ruby, etc.)

Comment: Really nice answer @Elazar

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it is correct, ada?

Comment: Thank you so much. However,I will continue to think about it.

Comment: I have wanted the same function as you say.